# Which is better to Connect to SQL Server database? ADO.net directly or WCF?

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, ado.net

I use ADO.net classes to connect to SQL Server database. When i connecting to remote computer database based on WAN, it works very slow. I know it's normal. I want to speed up database connection between server and client. Now question is this: If i install a service on server computer and send database requests from client computer to it through WCF, is better than to connect through ADO.net directly to server? Is there an other way?

Comment: The DB look-ups will be faster on the sever, but obviously you still need to transmit the data over the network which is likely the real bottleneck.  The best way to speed up DB calls is to reduce the amount of data you retrieve to the minimum you require, reduce the number of DB calls as much as possible, and to tune the DB with indexes that will increase the performance of your queries.  Your strategy could work if you need to pull a lot of data and crunch it in memory to generate a smaller amount of data that is then sent to the client.

Comment: Will it be faster to connect to the database through a WCF service or directly using ADO.Net? That depends on the actual bottle necks. If the main bottle neck is the data transfer between the database and the application, a WCF service that takes the data from the database and compress it before sending to the client application might be a good solution - providing the compress/decompress overhead + the wcf overhead not too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two concepts are only loosely related:

- WCF is for making web calls.
- ADO is for querying the database.

ADO is among the fastest ways to get data. If your speeds are slow, it's something else. Stackoverflow for example uses Dapper, sitting right on top of ADO for its calls.

Things to consider:

- What is "slow". A 2 second query for multiple joins and hundreds of thousands of rows isn't bad.
- Is your query optimized
- Are you returning only required data
- Is your database optimized
- Are you sure it's the query. Thousands of rows might take 65ms in the query but much longer to render to a grid if done certain ways.

There's a bit to consider here, and muddling terms will make it worse.

Start by grabbing your ADO query and running the SQL in SSMS directly. What is the time there? If it's slow, optimize. If it's fast, move down the stack until you find where the slow parts are and address that.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,

- Using a WCF service better and safe.
- This is because whenever you use ADO.net you have to store ConnectionString in application but WCF you dont.
- Of course ADO is faster than WCF this is because You connect WCF and WCF connect ADO.